# how to get a full list from a function python

Tags: python

I'm totally new about python. So here is my issue.

```
def visitdir(path):
    result = []
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for filepath in files:
            result = ''.join(os.path.join(root,filepath))
            print result            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = raw_input("Please input the folder you want to walk:")
    visitdir(path)
```

It will give the full list while inputting the folder I want to walk.
But if I modified it as below:

```
import os, sys
def visitdir(path):
    result = []
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for filepath in files:
            result = ''.join(os.path.join(root,filepath))
            return result            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = raw_input("Please input the folder you want to walk:")
    final = visitdir(path)
    print final
```

It will only give one item from selected path. If I just want to the same result as previous one, How do i invoke the function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because it is returning on the first iteration of the second for-loop. Likely, you'll want to append to your result list, and then process the data in your list to get the output you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` terminates execution of given function.

One of easiest ways of doing it would be to `yield` values and make generator from your function.

```
def visitdir(path):
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for filepath in files:
            result = ''.join(os.path.join(root,filepath))
            yield result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = raw_input("Please input the folder you want to walk:")
    print list(visitdir(path))
    # or
    for p in visitdir(path):
        print p
```

Another alternative would be to store all intermediate results in list and return said list.

```
def visitdir(path):
    results = []
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for filepath in files:
            result = ''.join(os.path.join(root,filepath))
            results.append(result)            
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = raw_input("Please input the folder you want to walk:")
    print visitdir(path)
    # or
    for p in visitdir(path):
        print p
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it gives back what I want to. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `return` you finish the function flow and return the value. 
Also why do you create the list 'result' and then override it with the string?

I think what you meant to do is something like this:

```
def visitdir(path):
    result = []
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for filepath in files:
            filename = ''.join(os.path.join(root,filepath))
            result.append(filename)
    return result
```

eg filling up the list with results and returning it in the end.

Another thing you could do is to use [yield](https://pythontips.com/2013/09/29/the-python-yield-keyword-explained/).

Answer (score 0):

You should append the results to the results list that you created.

```
def visitdir(path):
    result = []
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
        for filepath in files:
            result.append(''.join(os.path.join(root,filepath)))
    return result
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = raw_input("Please input the folder you want to walk:")
    visitdir(path)
```